# updating value in recylerview

Tags: android, data-binding, android-recyclerview

i have a recylerview whose item contains two textview (Name, Time), i have a timer running on different thread which runs every second and i want to update Time textview value of **specific item** in my list. however due to large data i can't add timer value in my arraylist data every second. how should i pass time value to my adapter and refresh UI every second without passing data in my arraylist, notifying adapter and relying on Bindview to refresh UI.

```
public class MyListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyListAdapter.ContactViewHolder>
 {
public ArrayList<Users> data;
private Context context;

public MyListAdapter(ArrayList<Users> dataList, Context context)
{
    this.data = dataList;
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.
            from(parent.getContext()).
            inflate(R.layout.card_layout, parent, false);

    return new ContactViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ContactViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    Users user = data.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(user.getName());
    holder.time.setText("00:00");
}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return this.data.size();
}



class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
{

    TextView name, time;

    public ContactViewHolder(View v)
    {
        super(v);
        name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_layout_name_txt);
        time = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_layout_time_txt);

    }

}
}





recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.fragment_recyclerview);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
LinearLayoutManager manager=new    LinearLayoutManager(context,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);





    myTimer = new Timer();
    myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            TimerMethod();
        }

    }, 0, 1000);


private void TimerMethod()
{

    this.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);
}

public Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
    // want to update time in specific item in recylerview

    }
};
```

Comment: Do you have to display the same time in all the rows or is it different times?

Comment: Please check my answer!

Comment: @MalithLakshan running timer in just one item, nothing on other items. and action of starting and stopping the timer will be on click of that item.

Answer (score 1):

I reached out the solution using RxJava and RxAndroid. I hope that it might be helpful.

I created a list with names. You start the timer clicking at name. Each name has one specific timer.

My activity looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(buildAdapter());
    }

    private RecyclerView.Adapter buildAdapter() {
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

        names.add("Rodrigo");
        names.add("Magno");
        names.add("Lucas");
        names.add("Henrique");
        names.add("Marcelo");
        names.add("Nadilson");
        names.add("Rafael");
        names.add("Walmyr");
        names.add("Haroldo");
        names.add("Samir");
        names.add("Eugênio");
        names.add("Leonardo");
        names.add("Maurício");
        names.add("Júlio");

        return new Adapter(this, names);
    }
}
```

There goes my `Adapter`.

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.CustomViewHolder> {
    private final static String TAG = Adapter.class.getSimpleName();

    private final List<String> items;
    private final PublishSubject<Event> publishSubject = PublishSubject.create();
    private final Map<String, Subscription> subscriptions;
    private final Context context;

    public Adapter(Context context, List<String> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
        this.subscriptions = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.holder_layout, parent, false);
        return new CustomViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String name = items.get(position);
        holder.bind(name);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView textViewName, textViewTimer;
        private Subscription tempSubscription;

        public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            textViewTimer = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
        }

        private void bind(String name) {
            textViewName.setText(name);

            if (tempSubscription != null)
                tempSubscription.unsubscribe();

            tempSubscription = publishSubject
                    .filter(event -> event.getName().equals(name))
                    .map(event -> event.getElapsedTime())
                    .map(elapsedTime -> String.format("%ds", elapsedTime))
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(formattedElapsedTime -> textViewTimer.setText(formattedElapsedTime), Adapter.this::handleError);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Subscription subscription = subscriptions.get(name);

                if (subscription == null || subscription.isUnsubscribed()) {
                    subscription = startTimer(name);
                    subscriptions.put(name, subscription);
                } else {
                    subscription.unsubscribe();
                    textViewTimer.setText("0s");
                }
            });
        }

        private Subscription startTimer(String name) {
            return Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.io())
                    .onBackpressureDrop()
                    .map(milliseconds -> new Event(name, milliseconds))
                    .subscribe(publishSubject::onNext, Adapter.this::handleError);
        }
    }

    private void handleError(Throwable t) {
        Log.e(TAG, "failure listening events", t);
    }
}
```

And my `Event`.

```
public class Event {
    private String name;
    private Long elapsedTime;

    public Event(String name, Long elapsedTime) {
        this.name = name;
        this.elapsedTime = elapsedTime;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Long getElapsedTime() {
        return elapsedTime;
    }
}
```

You can see the full functional example in [my Github](https://github.com/rodrigohenriques).

Project URL: https://github.com/rodrigohenriques/rx-timer-list

Comment: Want to emphasize `tempSubscription.unsubscribe();`. If you don't do this, any time `onBindViewHolder` is called it will create a new subscription, so be sure to save the subscription and dispose it.

Answer (score 1):

Make the timer observable and pass it as a variable to your binding instances.
This will update those rows properly as timer ticks (and dispatches change event).
I also suggest using the adapter we released on github so that your updates happen very efficiently.

https://github.com/google/android-ui-toolkit-demos/tree/master/DataBinding/DataBoundRecyclerView